# Whatever happened to this off-topic option?

Tags: discussion

> Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme,
>   distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for
>   Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

I no longer see it as an option, these are the only options:

[image]

Considering this is used quite often, we shouldn't have to select other and type it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but thinking about it, maybe that it is suggested we use Needs Focus, Needs Details, or Opinion-based instead which should cover the reasons above? Needs Focus/Needs Details could be used to suggest the asker move away from documentation-based question to something more specific and Opinion-based could be used for recommendations?

Comment: We decided to temporary remove it, since that closing reason was used for questions that weren't asking for recommendation or to find any off-site resources.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – I always find it difficult when decisions in the SE network are executed that way. This should be a Meta post, naming the problem and asking for ideas to improve.

Comment: See https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/custom-close-reasons-for-2020

Comment: @leymannx It was necessary, since nobody flagged any question wrongly closed with that reason to report it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – I still don't understand entirely. Can you maybe make that an answer with a little bit more context?

Comment: @leymannx A user posted on this meta because his question was closed for this reason and I closed some questions because the wrongly selected closing reason was this one.